# Why has an ASP.NET MVC project a WebApiConfig.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When I create a MVC4 project and choose basic mvc project 
I find WebApi related code why this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Microsoft hope that you will use Web API 8-)

http://www.asp.net/web-api

If you don't want to, you can ignore it or even comment it in Global.asax

```
// WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```